# Starting two Scala Finagle ListeningServers at once

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I need to start two [Finagle ListeningServer](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/com/twitter/finagle/ListeningServer.html)s at once because I have to implement two different traits that extend `ListeningServer`.

```scala
/* A simplified example to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do */

trait FirstListeningServer extends ListeningServer {

  def buildFirstServer() = ???

  def main(): Unit = {
    val server = buildFirstServer()
    closeOnExit(server)
    Await.ready(server)
  }

}

trait SecondListeningServer extends ListeningServer {

  def buildSecondServer() = ???

  def main(): Unit = {
    val server = buildSecondServer()
    closeOnExit(server)
    Await.ready(server)
  }

}
```

Basically, each `ListeningServer` is a `com.twitter.util.Awaitable` and whenever I have to instantiate a new `ListeningServer` I use [`Await.ready(myListeningServer)`](https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Await$.html).

```scala
class MyServer extends FirstListeningServer with SecondListeningServer {

  override def main(): Unit = {
    val firstServer = buildFirstServer()
    closeOnExit(firstServer)
    val secondServer = buildSecondServer()
    closeOnExit(secondServer)
    Await.all(firstServer, secondServer)
  }
}
```

Now I'm not sure if using `Await.all()` is the right choice in order to start several `ListeningServer`s concurrently. I would have used `com.twitter.util.Future.collect()` but I have two `Awaitable`s.

> `def all(awaitables: Awaitable[_]*): Unit`
>
> Returns after all actions have completed.

I'm using Scala 2.12 and Twitter 20.3.0.

Comment: Instead of awaiting multiple times, it will be good if you can return future from both buildFirstServer and buildSecondServer and then use join and then await on the same.

https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/com/twitter/util/Future.html#join[B](other:com.twitter.util.Future[B]):com.twitter.util.Future[(A,B)]

Comment: What I didn't say is that I cannot refactor/change `FirstListeningServer` and `SecondListeningServer`. I just receive the Awaitables. It would be easier to have a series of Futures in order to use a `Future.collect()`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the await.all, but the problem since you are awaiting it will be awaiting till the HTTP server is running, so the second listening server wont start is the question right?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will actually start concurrently or if it will wait for the first server to return (and actually be closed).

Answer (score 0):

```
com.twitter.util.Await.all(listeningServer1, listeningServer2)
```

will start both in parallel.

Independent from this You can stop them both e.g. with the help of:

```
  listeningServer1.close(10.seconds)
  listeningServer2.close(10.seconds)
```